# Limit the scope of css inside a page

Tags: css

I have a page where i can define an html template with a modal editor and this template is then put inside a div (like a preview).
Inside this text area there will be Html/css (maybe Js idk).

The problem i have is that the css put inside the template can affect the whole page. The user is aware of the divs and stuff he's creating inside his template but isn't aware of the webpage content itself.

I would like to limit the scope of this CSS. I thought about switching the container div to an iframe. But it looks complicated as i must get the content back to save it afterwards.

Is there a good solution here?

This could be a template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container{
            border-style: none;
            margin-left: 4%;
            margin-right: 4%;
            }
            td{
            line-height: 150%;
            padding-top: 1%;
            padding-bottom: 1%;
            }
            .solidTableFull{
                //stuff
            }
            .solidTableMarge{
                //stuff
            }
            span{
            color: #0070c0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="zoom: 100%;">
                //stuff
                //stuff
                //stuff
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can tackle the situation is by forcing/instructing the user to type the html and css in two separate textarea.

textarea one:  filters out any html `<style>` tag blocks (you can use jQuery(textarea_content).find('style').remove(); )

textarea two: filters any html tag or keep it simple

As a first step, before rendering the content on a target page, you could enclose the html content with a div and assign a dynamically generated classname

then the next step is to use regexp to extract the css definitions as array items and prepend the dynamically generated classname that we did in step1

if its hard to define a proper regexp, you could use string split() method... eg: `csstextarea_content.split('}')`

This should give you some ideas... I hope

Comment: i'll dig into this idea of parsing/updating css as there're multiple comments talking about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make all the CSS in the container dependent on your container class. So for example, instead of having a style for `div`, you need to create a style for `#container div`.

This will only affect the divs inside your container div, not the whole page.

Comment: end user is the one defining the css... (css along with html inside a textarea control box) so that idea's way too complicated if we need to parse css and assign specific scopes

Comment: But the css created is typed by the user. I can't tell him to add #container before all his css rules. And this template could be paste in, for example, a html mail. That wouldn't work if i'm not wrong right?

Comment: you can add it under the hood... search for sass or less what can help you a lot

Comment: @EduardVoid can you elaborate?
This html is not exactly 'written' by the user (although he could), it is generated with a "html editor".

Comment: @EduardVoid think of his requirement as a dynamic advertisement block but the only catch here is that didn't bound inside an iframe... so it(css in the advertisement block) can affect any element on the page

Comment: take the input, extract css, add prefix and apply it. you can't do this by a simple way

Comment: another (also non-trivial) option is shadowing the DOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM please take a look on the browser support

Answer (score 0):

the simple and maybe the only option is to give some ID (classname if you have more instances displayed at one time) to your preview div and then prefix every css rule with the same selector

```css
strong { color: #FF0000; }
#preview strong { color: #0000FF; }
```

```html
<div>
  No preview <strong>content</strong>
  <div id="preview">
    <strong>Preview</strong> content.
  </div>
 </div>
```

take into the count, that some parent css can be applied to your preview too. For avoiding this, you can use `:not(#preview)` selector